# Adding large numbers together using char and returning the value. Pointers error

Tags: c, pointers

Hey guys my program assignment ask for me to write a program to add big numbers together and return it by calling a function. I am having difficulties understanding how to return the value back to be displayed. I am confident my errors are in my incorrect usage of pointers, but I do not understand it enough to figure it out. Please help!

I have put an arrow next to the lines where I think the problem is but I don't know how to solve it.
Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *addlarge(char, char, char); <--


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
unsigned char number1 [256] = {'0'};
unsigned char number2 [256] = {'0'};
unsigned char result [256] = {0};

//ask for numbers
printf ("Please enter a number upto 255 digits long:\n");
scanf ("%s", number1);
printf ("Please enter another number upto 255 digits long:\n");
scanf ("%s", number2);
char *result1 = addLarge(*number1, *number2, *result); <--
printf("\nThe sum is %s\n", result1); <--
}

char *addLarge(char *number1, char *number2, char *result) <--
{
    int x, z, b, padding1, padding2, padding, y=0, sum, carry=0;

//right aligns the numbers
    x = strlen(number1);
    padding1 = 255 - x;
    memmove(number1+padding1,number1,x);
    memset(number1, 0, padding1);

    z = strlen(number2);
    padding2 = 255 - z;
    memmove(number2+padding2,number2,z);
    memset(number2, 0, padding2);

//works it out
    for(y=254; y>=0; y--) {
    if ( (number1[y] != 0) || (number2[y] != 0) ) {
        if ( (number1[y] != 0) && (number2[y] != 0) ) {
        sum = 0;
        sum += carry;
        carry = 0;
        sum += number1[y] - '0' + number2[y] - '0';
        carry = sum / 10;
        result[y+1] = sum % 10 + '0';
        }
    else {
    sum = 0;
    sum += carry;
    carry = 0;
    sum += number1[y] - '0' + number2[y];
    carry = sum / 10;
    result[y+1] = sum % 10 + '0';
    }
}

//adds the carries
if ((number1[y] == 0) && (number2[y] == 0) && (carry==1)){
        result[y+1] = 1 + '0';
        carry = 0;
    }
}

//shifts number back
    for (b=255; result[b] != 0; b--){
//    result[b] = result[b];
    }
    padding = strlen(result) + 1;
    system ("PAUSE");
  return result; <--
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? compilation errors? wrong results? Clearly your function signature for addChar is not the same as your forward declaration.

Comment: You've posted a bunch of code and said "I have issues. I've marked lines where I think the issue is", but you have not explained a specific problem and have not asked a specific question. What **exactly** is the problem you're having with the code you've posted? StackOverflow isn't a site for "Here's a bunch of code. Can you guess my problem or question and tell me how to fix it?" posts.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the only error in the code, but notice that your prototype looks like this:

```
char *addlarge(char, char, char);
```

and your function is defined as follows:

```
char *addLarge(char *number1, char *number2, char *result) {
   ...
}
```

Try changing the prototype to match the definition:

```
char *addlarge(char*, char*, char*);
```

Hope this helps!